# Java producer consumer threads

Tags: java, keyword

how to implement producer consumer problem with multiple producers and multiple consumers??
how should we create threads?

Answer (score 1):

Create a producer and a consumer class both of which are <strike>extending Thread class</strike> implementing Runnable interface, and call them whenever you need. Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Instead of extending `Thread`, I'd suggest implementing `Runnable` or `Callable<V>` and wrapping the `Runnable` in a `Thread` or scheduling the `Callable<V>` using an `Executor`.

Comment: @justkt that does the trick :). I didn't know that though. Is that for  performance issues? Why do we not extend Thread?

Comment: In general I've always been under the impression that composition is to be preferred over inheritance.  Having a Runnable that is part of a Thread is composition.  Having a Thread subclass is inheritance.  It's for maintainability purposes.  From Sun "[Employing] a Runnable object, is more general, because the Runnable object can subclass a class other than Thread."

Answer (score 0):

```
ConcurrentQueue q = new ConcurrentQueue(100);

ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);

service.execute(new Producer(q));

for (int i=0; i < 18; i++) {
    service.execute(new Consumer(q));
}
```

Where both `Consumer` and `Producer` are custom classes that extend Runnable and take a `Queue` as their constructor argument.

Comment: I guess the multiple consumers part of the question is left as an exercise for the reader?

Comment: Generally in the model the Producer is doing nothing more then queuing up job requests (very fast task) and so only one is needed.  The consumers on the other hand take a job from the queue and then [possibly] do some long running task, thus more are needed to service the queue.

Comment: That's the normal Producers-Consumers problem I've seen, but the OP specifically mentioned multiple producers.

Comment: Ahh I didn't see that.  I think he should be able to figure it out from this example:)

Answer (score 0):

This class connects any number of producers to any number of consumers, via a single bounded blocking queue.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.CancellationException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public abstract class ProducerConsumer<E> {

    private final BlockingQueue<Optional<E>> queue;

    public ProducerConsumer(
            int numProducerThreads, int numConsumerThreads, int queueCapacity) {
        if (numProducerThreads < 1 || numConsumerThreads < 1 || queueCapacity < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Optional<E>>(queueCapacity);
        final ExecutorService executor = 
                Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numProducerThreads + numConsumerThreads);
        try {
            // Start producer threads
            final List<Future<?>> producerFutures = new ArrayList<>();
            final AtomicInteger numLiveProducers = new AtomicInteger();
            for (int i = 0; i < numProducerThreads; i++) {
                producerFutures.add(executor.submit(() -> {
                    numLiveProducers.incrementAndGet();
                    // Run producer
                    producer();
                    // When last producer finishes, deliver poison pills to consumers
                    if (numLiveProducers.decrementAndGet() == 0) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < numConsumerThreads; j++) {
                            queue.put(Optional.empty());
                        }
                    }
                    return null;
                }));
            }
            // Start consumer threads
            final List<Future<?>> consumerFutures = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < numConsumerThreads; i++) {
                consumerFutures.add(executor.submit(() -> {
                    // Run Consumer
                    consumer();
                    return null;
                }));
            }
            // Wait for all producers to complete
            completionBarrier(producerFutures, false);
            // Shut down any consumers that are still running after producers complete
            completionBarrier(consumerFutures, false);
        } finally {
            executor.shutdownNow();
        }
    }

    private static void completionBarrier(List<Future<?>> futures, boolean cancel) {
        for (Future<?> future : futures) {
            try {
                if (cancel) {
                    future.cancel(true);
                }
                future.get();
            } catch (CancellationException | InterruptedException e) {
                // Ignore
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    protected void produce(E val) {
        try {
            queue.put(Optional.of(val));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    protected Optional<E> consume() {
        try {
            return queue.take();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    /** Producer loop. Call {@link #produce(E)} for each element. */
    public abstract void producer();

    /**
     * Consumer thread. Call {@link #consume()} to get each successive element,
     * until an empty {@link Optional} is returned.
     */
    public abstract void consumer();
}
```

Use as follows:

```
new ProducerConsumer<Integer>(/* numProducerThreads = */ 1, /* numConsumerThreads = */ 4,
        /* queueCapacity = */ 10) {
    @Override
    public void producer() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            System.out.println("Producing " + i);
            produce(i);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void consumer() {
        for (Optional<Integer> opt; (opt = consume()).isPresent; ) {
            int i = opt.get();
            System.out.println("Got " + i);
        }
    }
};
```